# Receiving single training sample (instead of a batch) in a customized train_step function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement WGAN_GP in tensorflow2. I created a class by subclassing tf.keras.Model, so that I can custom my own train_step() function. The code for my class roughly looks like this:

```
class WGANGP(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WGANGP, self).__init__()

    def compile(self, gen_optimizer, disc_optimizer):
        super(WGANGP, self).compile()

    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, real_images):
```

Because my training samples are 64by64 RGB images in a tensorflow Dataset with a batch size of 64:

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(64)
test = list(train_dataset.take(1))
len(test)  ### outputs 1
test[0].shape  ### outputs (64,64,64,3)
```

So I expect the "real_images" variable in the train_step() function to be a batch of my training samples, that is to say it should have a shape of [64,64,64,3].

But when I add a `print(real_images.shape)` in the train_step() function, I get a output of`(None, 64, 64, 3)`.

That means it's only one single training sample, not a batch of them. I really can't understand why this happens. Is this a bug? Or maybe there is something wrong with my code?

By adding

```
print(tf.shape(real_images))
print(tf.shape(real_images)[0])
print(tf.shape(real_images).numpy())
```

to the train_step() function, I receive outputs like this:

```
Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: Show the output of `print(tf.shape(real_images))`

Comment: `@AloneTogether` it outputs `Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)`, I then tried `print(tf.shape(real_images).numpy())`, and it outputs an error of `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Comment: I have the same problem. Apparently adding a `run_eagerly=True` in `model.compile` solves the problem, but the training probably becomes slower. Decorating the `train_step` method with `tf.function` helps fasten up the training. But I am not sure if it could be even faster.